# Convert JavaScript function to closed-form expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

In my library, I want to take a one-argument JavaScript function that inputs and outputs doubles, to a closed-form expression (in a string) using those statements:

1. The input variable `x`
2. Any integer or decimal number ex. `2.5`
3. Unary minus (JS `-a`): `a.neg()`
4. Addition (JS `a+b`): `a.add(b)`
5. Subtraction (JS `a-b`): `a.sub(b)`
6. Multiplication (JS `a*b`): `a.mul(b)`
7. Division operator (JS `a/b`): `a.div(b)`
8. Exponent operator (JS `Math.pow(a,b)`): `a.pow(b)`
9. Logarithm ooperator (JS `Math.log(b)/Math.log(a)`): `a.log(b)`

If the function cannot be represented using these statements, it should produce an asymptotic approximation of the function that uses the statements. Here is some examples of the intended behavior:

```js
    //Normal square function
    function sq(a) {
      return a * a
    }

    /*
    This outputs exactly the same as sq for integers, but is implemented recursively
    */
    function sq_rec(a) {
      if (a === 0) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return sq_rec(a - 1) + (2 * a - 1)
      }
    }

    console.log(toClosed(sq)) //Should return "x.mul(x)"
    console.log(toClosed(sq_rec)) //Should STILL return "x.mul(x)"
    console.log(toClosed(Math.log2)) //Should return "x.log(2)"
    console.log(toClosed(Math.sin)) //Should return an approximation of sine
```

Comment: You want to write a function that figures out what another function is doing, and returns new code that's equivalent using your list of functions?

Comment: I don't think it's really possible, especially for the recursive function.

Comment: Your recursive function isn't really recursive. It's calling `sq()` instead of `sq_rec()`.

Comment: @Barmar My mistake, I mixed up the old version of the example code with new one.

Comment: I still think it's not possible to analyze arbitrary code like this. And the first thing you need to write is a JavaScript parser in JS.

Comment: @Barmar I am aware of that, but I was actually thinking of using something more like a predictive model (analyzing input/outputs instead of the code) to do it.

Comment: This sounds more like a CS project than a SO question.

Comment: Analyze input/output? So you're going to call the function on lots of different inputs, and try to find a pattern in the outputs, and figure out how that corresponds to your list of functions? Good luck with that. Maybe you could train a NN to do it.

Comment: I suspect you would be solving a major problem in computability if you could write such a thing.